# Which InApp purchase suite for magazine issue product?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am implementing newsstand application,we are selling issue for each month either by subscription or by direct purchase for old issues(price is different for all issue)

I have already done with subscription (auto renewable) and its working fine.

My Concern is about direct InApp purchase of old issues.
Which type of InApp purchase best suite for my app consumable or non consumable?

If I choose non-consumable type I need to create new product id for each issue(issue are dynamic to that will be lots of product id i have to create)

If I choose consumable type I can use same product id for all the issues - non need to manage InApp from iTunes but in this case Price for all the issue will be same.

My Question is, Is there any solution using which I can handle InApp purchase of dynamic issue where price for all item is not same and also don't want to create new product id for new issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for above situation....

We must use `non-consumable` In-App Purchase for such kind of applications.
If we use `consumable` In-App Purchase for magazine issue, Apple will reject your application.

And Ya, We need to create CMS which is responsible for managing product id.

Let me know if anybody have any issue in Newsstand app.

Thanks

Comment: looks pretty way to achieve it.But how you managed for a single issue to provide the In-app as well as Subscription i.e How you managed to bind IAP as well Subscription for the same magazine issue?